# Python-MultiThreading: Can MultiThreading improve "for loop" performance?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

As far as my understanding:

- MultiThread is an ideal option for **I/O** applications.

Therefore, I test a "for loop" code without any I/O.
(As following code)

Howerver, it can reduce the execution time from 6.3s to 3.7s.

Is the result correct ?

or any mistake in my suppose ?

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time

# normal
l = []
s = time.time()
for i in range(0, 10000):
    for j in range(i):
        l.append(j * 10)

e = time.time()
print(f"case1: {e-s}") # 6.3 sec

# multiThread
def func(x):
    for i in range(x):
        l_.append(i * 10)

with ThreadPool(50) as pool:
    l_ = []
    s = time.time()

    pool.map(func, range(0, 10000))

    e = time.time()
    print(f"case2: {e-s}") # 3.7 sec
```

Comment: Re, "Can MultiThreading improve "for loop" performance?" That question makes no sense. Threads are not interchangeable with `for` loops. There may be _some_ algorithms in which `pool.map(...)` is a workable alternative to `for...:...`, but there are many others that count on the loop to do things in a certain order that cannot be guaranteed by parallel threads.

Comment: Re, "Is the result correct ?" I can't comment on the _timing_ that you report, but the threads in your multi-thread version append to the global list, `l_`, without any synchronization. I am not a Python expert, and I don't know whether `l_.append(...)` is thread-safe or not, but in most other programming languages it would _not_ be safe. Doing that without a mutex lock in other languages could result in the list being incorrect at the end of the run or, could even result in a program crash.

Comment: @SolomonSlow `append` is guaranteed to be threadsafe by the GIL.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, Yeah, I wondered about that. Yet another reason why the GIL will never go away (at least, not in any language called "Python 2.x" or "Python 3.x.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are seeing is just python specializing the function by using faster op-codes for the multithreaded version as it is a function that is called multiple times, See PEP 659 [Specializing Adaptive Interpreter](https://peps.python.org/pep-0659/), this only true for python 3.11 and later.

changing the non-multithreaded version to also be a function that is called multiple times give almost the same performance (python 3.11)

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import time

l = []
def f2(i):
    for j in range(i):
        l.append(j * 10)
def f1():
    # normal
    for i in range(0, 10_000):
        f2(i)

s = time.time()
f1()
e = time.time()
print(f"case1: {e-s}")


# multiThread
def func(x):
    global l_
    for i in range(x):
        l_.append(i * 10)

with ThreadPool(50) as pool:
    l_ = []
    s = time.time()

    pool.map(func, range(0, 10_000))

    e = time.time()
    print(f"case2: {e-s}")
```

```
case1: 3.9744303226470947
case2: 4.036579370498657
```

threading in python **IS** going to be **slower** for functions that need the GIL, and manipulating lists requires the GIL so **using threading will be slower**, python threads only improve performance if the GIL is dropped (which happens on IO and C external libraries calls), if this is ever not the case then either your code drops the GIL or your benchmark is flawed.

Comment: I think you are right. When I test a "inner loop function" with single thread, it spend the same time with multithread (case 2)

Answer (score 0):

In general it is true that multithreading is better suited for I/O bound operations. However, in this trivial case it is clearly not so.

It's worth pointing out multiprocessing will outperform either of the strategies implemented in OP's code.

Here's a rewrite that demonstrates 3 techniques:

```
from functools import wraps
from time import perf_counter


def timeit(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = perf_counter() - start
        print(f'Function {func.__name__}{args} {kwargs} Took {duration:.4f} seconds')
        return result
    return _wrapper

@timeit
def case1():
    l = []
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        for j in range(i):
            l.append(j * 10)

def process(n):
    l = []
    for j in range(n):
        l.append(j * 10)

@timeit
def case2():
    with TPE() as tpe:
        tpe.map(process, range(0, 10_000))

@timeit
def case3():
    with PPE() as ppe:
        ppe.map(process, range(0, 10_000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for func in case1, case2, case3:
        func()
```

**Output:**

```
Function case1() {} Took 3.3104 seconds
Function case2() {} Took 2.6354 seconds
Function case3() {} Took 1.7245 seconds
```

In this case the trivial processing is probably outweighed by the overheads in thread management. If case1 was even more CPU intensive you'd probably begin to see rather different results

Answer (score 0):

Multi threading is ideal for I/O applications because it allows a server/host to accept multiple connections, and if a single request is slow or hangs, it can continue serving the other connections without blocking them.

That isn't mutually exclusive from speeding up a simple for loop execution, if there's no coordination between threads required like in your trivial example above. If each execution of loop is completely independent of any other executions, then it's also very well suited to multi threading, and that's why you're seeing a speed up.